# cannot load windows media within firefox browser

Tags: firefox, windows-media-player

I recently re-installed windows and everything on it and besides this one issue everything is working much smoother again...

the only problem is that I cannot load windows media content (for example *.asx) within my firefox browser.

If i go to a page which embeds such streaming media, the media player never loads, and if i type the full url to the asx in the address bar, nothing loads.

I have "Windows Media Player Plug-in Dynamic Link Library 3.0.2.629" in my plugin list.

what might i have broken?

cheers, p.

Comment: Do you happen to have VLC installed?

Comment: yes! but i disabled the plugin thinking it might be a conflict ...

Comment: I'll post an answer in a second...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VLC is known to break some Windows Media Player playbacks, disabling the plugin won't work. You can remove VLC entirely and re-install without the browser plugins. Also remove the Windows Media Player plugin and re-install that. That should restore proper playback.

If you do want to keep the VLC plugin, remove VLC and the WMP plugin, re-install the WP plugin and the re-install VLC. However on some occasions this does not fix the problem.

Comment: @pstanton Let me know!

Comment: i've uninstalled vlc and windows media player 11 but the wmp firefox plugin is still there. loading an asx now shows a black screen in firefox (instead of a white one before) but no video loads. am i on the right track still? should i install wmp again?

Comment: @pstanton you should uninstall the plugin, not WMP itself... It should be available in your remove software window in Config panel as "Windows Media Player Firefox plugin"

Comment: no it's not in the remove program list, never was. i'm using xp.

Comment: maybe this is a problem caused by copying my firefox application data folder across from the old windows install ... ? maybe firefox thinks the wmp plugin exists when it doesn't?

Comment: @pstanton that quite a possibility. You could try to reinstall firefox to try it.

Comment: ok, i've gone through a full uninstall-reinstall process for wmp and vlc and instead of just showing a blank page, firefox now launches VLC. I would prefer if it used the WMP plugin and embedded the video, but at least something is happening.